# JPA Multiple FK from same tables

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

Have two tables named Employee and Order.
The relations between the tables Employee (1) -- (*) Order.
Also the Order has two FK from Employee, named EmployeeEncoder and EmployeeUpdater.

I am using EclipseLink (JPA 2.0) under Netbeans 7.0 using JDK 7.

Creating an order with respect to the employee logged wasn't a hassle.
When it comes to updating the order and setting the EmployeeUpdater wherein the EmployeeEncoder equals EmployeeEncoder, the Employee record is duplicated.

How could I resolve this thread in a way duplication of the records on the EmployeeUpdater won't be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you persist a new Order it should reference an Employee from the same persistence context (EntityManager).  Try doing a find() for the Employee and setting the Order's employee to that.  You could also use merge() instead of persist.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are setting Employee object with primary key value null or 0 to Order. So you got duplicated employees. You might want to debug using IDE to see the value.

Set the cascade type of Order to Employee as `CascadeType.MERGE`

Comment: Among the CascadeTypes... What should I use? http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/